# custom tableView cell performing tow action (showing detail and performing action without showing details)

Tags: objective-c, swift, parsing

I'm struggling with getting a button on a custom tableView. I have a Review (rating) feature on a custom tableView cell. The user can give rating on these cells. I am able to get the rating working, but don't know how to save the rating.

I thought of using a button inside the custom tableView cell, clicking which will save the rating in the parse.com backend.

I don't want to use didSelectAtIndexPath because I am showing details on the cell on the cell tap. So the only way to submit the review is to use the button inside the cell. I found a way to do it in Objective C, but can't make it work in Swift. Can anyone help?

```
-(void)someAction:(id)sender {
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"current Row=%d", senderButton.tag);

PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex: senderButton.tag];
NSLog(@"%@". tempObject.objectId);
}
```

This is how I am getting reference to the custom cell in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
Cell.button.tag = indexPath.row // get's the button tag in sync with indexRow
Cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) // Button action function
```

I am not even sure if this is the right way to do this. I Would appreciate any other recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented the someAction function in Swift? You have to put a colon after the action string to ensure you call the right action function (with the sender object). Leaving out the colon will call someAction(), when you want to call `someAction(_sender: UIButton?)`.

```
Cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then write the function the same way you did in Obj-C

```
func someAction(senderButton: UIButton?) {
    println("current Row = \(senderButton.tag))
    // Save based on the tag of the button...
```

}

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason Xcode throws me an error: unrecognised selector sent. I had to do some changes in the code you send though as suggested by Xcode     func someAction(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let senderButton: UIButton = (sender as? UIButton)!
        println("current Row = \(senderButton.tag)")
        //resultLabel.text = "Button Tapped"
    } Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: That error means that the compiler can't find the someAction function. Did you add the colon to the action string? Also, make sure that the someAction method is in the same class where you added your target.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same target to every button:

```
Cell.button.addTarget(self, action: “someAction:”, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Watch the **:** here, this will activate the following function

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!){
    var btnsendtag:UIButton = sender
    if btnsendtag.tag == 1 {            
       println(“firstButton Pressed”)
    }
}
```

The **:** in your action makes sure it will call the function with the sender as parameter. This way you can get the tag of the button and see which button was tapped.

Comment: For some reason this is giving me error "unrecognised selector sent" (i did change the function to someAction as it is in the cellForRowAtIndexPath). But again, I will have this tableView updated with unknown number of rows. So I am not sure it would be a good idea to explicitly use hardcoded tag numbers in the function. The whole idea is to pass the rating generated (which I have it working) inside the tableview cell to save in the parse backend. For which I just want to perform save action on the row at which the button is placed. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The unrecognized selector is probably because you removed the **:** (at least this is how I read your comment) You don’t need to hard code the tags, again, the tag implementation was just an example on how to get (and use) the tag of the button. If you get the tag of the button you could use that as the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` to get the cell (and I hope the other important data) from the `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

---

Just editing  timgcarlson's answer as this is how it worked for me. 
I am using Xcode 6.3, swift 1.2

```
//This is placed in cellForRowAtIndexPath
Cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
Cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "someAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

//This is the action function
func someAction(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let senderButton: UIButton = (sender as? UIButton)!
    println("current Row = \(senderButton.tag)")
}
```

Timgcarlson answer helped me solve this. @timgcarlson Thank you for helping me out in this. Please see: I am posting edited version of your answer so that people who are using Xcode 6.3 Swift 1.2 will get the same results as I am getting.